# What does the number in TextMesh.lineSpacing refer to?

Tags: unity

I have a TextMesh with some text, and mutliple lines.

The 4 examples have these settings:

1. lineSpacing = 220, characterSize = 10
2. lineSpacing = 220, characterSize = 25
3. lineSpacing = 220, characterSize = 30
4. lineSpacing = 110, characterSize = 25

[image]

I don't understand what the lineSpacing number signifies. It's not pixels. As the relative spacing between lines stays the same with different character sizes, it doesn't seem to be proportional to characterSize either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bitmap font has glyphs that are 22 pixels high. So it looks like the `lineSpacing` property needs 10x the pixel height of the glyphs to have no gap between lines, and no overlap. I don't know why, but empirically this appears to work.

Seems related to this question:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/932474/unitys-textmesh-fontlineheight-and-the-number-975f.html

This is because when creating a Font, lineSpacing of the Font object defaults to 0.1:

[image]

But this property is not available except through the editor, apparently. >:(

Answer (score -1):

It's the space between the lines, it's not relative to size or font, it's an absolute value. [This should do.](http://puu.sh/hh9JP/0eda2ab44c.png)

Edit : I apologize for not understanding your question. Line spacing is in world units, it should snap to a pixel as long as its a multiple of 1 / pixels per meter.

Comment: I believe he's asking what the *units* are. It's pretty clear that "lineSpacing" refers to "space between the lines."

Comment: Josh is right. Why is it lineSpacing = 220 that makes this particular font have a gap of one font-pixel between the lines?

Comment: I fixed my answer, I apologize again.

Comment: How can it be world units, if the same linespacing in 1, 2, 3 result in different world unit distances?